# How do I make Visual Studio show up in Unity Preferences?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm quite new to Programming in general. I've learned basics, but that's about all. I was watching a tutorial, but I realized I was using Visual Studio Code instead of Visual Studio. While I was trying to change my External Script Editor, I could not find Visual Studio. I also cannot find it on my PC.

External Script Editor:

[image: My External Script Editor]

Answer (score 0):

No question is a dumb question so don't apologize for asking even if it is a basic thing.

Now to answer your question, please open the Visual Studio Installer and select modify.

After doing this in the gaming section and then select Game Development with Unity and modify your installation. Then restart Unity and try selecting Visual Studio from Unity.

[image]

Comment: I had already done this, but I just pressed the modify button again and it worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: sure... happy coding!